# Dependency error when installing OpenNMS

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, ubuntu-16.04, gnome-shell, opennms

When I tried to install the OpenNMS on Ubuntu 16.04 (with Gnome version) following the instructions of this link https://www.opennms.org/en/install-debian, I get the dependency error:

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/opennms-forge/opennms-install/archive/1.1.tar.gz | tar xz
$ cd opennms-install-1.1
$ sudo bash bootstrap-debian.sh
.......
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opennms : Depends: opennms-server (= 19.0.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: opennms-webapp-jetty (= 19.0.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: opennms-source (= 19.0.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Then I tried to install opennms-server by apt-get, and I get the other error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install opennms-server
.......
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opennms-server : Depends: opennms-common (= 19.0.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
```

And after I tried to install opennms-common by apt-get, and I get another error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install opennms-common
.......
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opennms-common : Depends: libdbd-pg-perl but it is not installable
                  Depends: libgetopt-mixed-perl but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libnet-snmp-perl but it is not going to be installed
```

How do I get it to install OpenNMS successfully on Gnome-Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Can't reproduce it on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 install. Did you run `apt update`?

Comment: Yes, I ran those commands after the `apt update` command.

Comment: Can you please verify if the problem still exists with a current 22.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? We have maintained the installer scripts which are version 1.3 now?